# How to add final overrider

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I add a "final overrider" to solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Shape
{
  virtual void print()
  {
    std::cout << "SHAPE" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~Shape() {}
};

struct Box : public virtual Shape
{
  void print() 
  {
    std::cout << "BOX" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Sphere : public virtual Shape
{
  void print() final override
  {
    std::cout << "SPHERE" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct GeoDisc : public Box, public Sphere
{
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Shape* s = new GeoDisc;

  s->print();

  delete s;

  return 0;
}
```

This is the error message:
31:8: error: no unique final overrider for 'virtual void Shape::print()' in 'GeoDisc'

Comment: Which function do you expect to be called?

Comment: I would like Sphere::print()

Comment: Impossible unless you remove the `final`. Once you do that, override `print()` in the GeoDisc, calling `Sphere::print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyword `final` in virtual method declaration prevents multiple inheritance, so if I tried to solve ambiguity in that case, it's a wrong approach. If both Box and Sphere would have final word, you'll get error "virtual function 'Shape::print' has more than one final overrider in 'GeoDisc'". The legal ambiguity solution would be:

```
struct Sphere : public virtual Shape
{
  void print() override
  {
    std::cout << "SPHERE" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct GeoDisc : public Box, public Sphere
{
  void print() final override
  {
    Sphere::print();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.